# Making a purchase from itunes store from ipad application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, itunes

I want to provide my user a way to purchase the paid/full version of my app when he is working on a lite version.I have a button on main menu where on clicking the button the user should be prompted for a password and finish the download similar as an app purchased from appstore application in ipad.

I have seen few apps doing so.Can someone suggest how can be achieved.Is there any framework provided by apple to communicate with itunes store

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you want:

```
SKStoreProductViewController
```

This will bring a modal view controller that allows your user to look at/buy your app without leaving your lite version.

Here's your link:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Making_Store_Purchases_with_the_SKStoreProductViewController_Class

Comment: that's great and thanks for the link.Learnt a new thing today.My application target IOS is 3.2 and how can i achieve this for a lower version of ios i.e other than ios 6.0?

Comment: @efrank You would test to see if SKStoreProductViewController is available (I think it shows how to in the post) and if it is, great, use it. If not, you will need to open a link (itms-apps://...) through that app store.

Comment: Yes i should look into those once again.Tnx for all the help once again.

Answer (score 2):

The are app are probably using an in app purchase to achieve this.

What they do is create on version of the app, which contains a option to unlock some of the restriction in the app by buying the full version of the by an in app purchase.

Apple has some nice documentation: [In-App Purchase](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [InAppPurchase](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

Mugunth Kumar's [MKStoreKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit) can help simplify in-app purchasing, if that's what they are using to do this.